# Singleton pattern with object lock

Tags: java, singleton

I'm trying to implement `Singleton` pattern for the below class. I should have only single instance of class `SingletonClass` at anytime in the JVM.

Does below code satisfy the Singleton pattern? please provide your suggestions.

```
public class SingletonClass {

    private static SingletonClass cache = null;
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();


    // creates one single instance of the class
    public static SingletonClass getInstance() {
        if (cache == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                if (cache == null) {
                    cache = new SingletonClass();
                }
            }
        }

        return cache;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SingletonClass.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Comment: @Kai I did check the questions on singleton. My question is that above code follows the pattern or not. Not how to implement one. I dont see its a duplicate for your downvote.

Comment: Then it is offtopic as well.

Comment: For the downvoters, show if the above code is in the linked duplicates. show some effort to read complete question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice article about different approaches of implementing a singleton pattern including your way:
[Reg's Tech article about Singleton](http://regrecall.blogspot.de/2012/05/java-singleton-pattern-thread-safe.html)

As mentioned in the article you should (if you want the pattern to be 100% thread safe) also declare the SingletonClass field as volatile. Also you do not need the Object as a lock. Just use `synchronized(SingletonClass.class)`

Comment: Thanks. yes the one difference is on synchronization subject. Is there a downside if I use `Object` as lock in Singleton ?

Comment: The only downside I encountered is that you're having an extra field in your class. But I have to say that the way of using a private static final Object as a lock might have the benefit of having a lock that is just accessable within your class. One could use SingletonClass.class outside your actual class as a lock.